# Handle many-to-many relationship in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a many-to-many relationship in a db I use with rails.

Say I have a schema that looks like this :

> **Cinemas**
>    - cinema_id
>    - name
>
> **Movies**
>    - movie_id
>    - name
>
> **Showtimes**
>    - showtime_id
>    - timestamp
>    - movie_id
>    - cinema_id

So basicaly : [Cinemas] 1 -- N [Showtimes] N -- 1 [Movies]

In one of my pages I have a cinema id and want to show the movies based on the cinema_id and group the showtimes per movie. I am not exactly sure on how to handle this properly. In .Net I would use a SelectMany linq operator and create a collection of movies but this does not seem to exists in ruby/rails.

One way to do this I think would be to do something like:

```
@showtimes = Showtime.where(:cinema_id, cinema_id)
@showtimes.each do |st|
  @movies.add(st.Movie) unless @movies.include? st.Movie
end
```

That would work ... but it seems ... ugly or it is just me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your schema, each showtime record will have exactly one movie and one cinema. You can easily get separate lists this way:

```
@showtimes = Showtime.where(:cinema_id, cinema_id).order(:showing_at)
@movies = @showtimes.map {|s| s.movie }
```

You might also want to look at the .group and .includes methods in ActiveRecord.

If you want to go straight to a list of movies showing at a certain cinema, you could also do this:

```
@movies = Movie.joins(:showtimes).where('showtimes.cinema_id = ?', cinema_id)
```

With that, you can loop over the movies and show each one's showtimes.

Comment: Very interesting. I'll be checking this tonight.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your associations setup correctly in your model, you should be able to do something like this:

Controller:

```
@showtimes = Showtime.where(:cinema_id, cinema_id)
```

View:

```
<%= @showtimes.each do |showtime| %>
    <p><%= showtime.movie.name %></p>  
<% end %>
```

Comment: True but with this is is not possible to have showtimes per movie in the view. You get the movies per showtime which is not exactly an interesting view.

Comment: Good point. Check out the group_by function. It should help you out.